# Combinational Circuit Double Check

Tags: logic, circuit

I've done the question completely but I was expecting it to be harder or at least more complicated than this, which is why it's sort of scaring me into thinking I might have missed something that made it very simple - as in x is always 0 and R5 is always 1 and there is only 1 output that results in a y of 1

If anyone doesn't mind going over my equations in comparison to the circuit on the left of the screenshot I would really appreciate it. Thanks

[image: http://tinypic.com/r/f586io/8]

The simplest way I can ask one of my questions without using a picture to clarify my result is - how would you use De Morgan's law to change (~A & D) & (~D + (B&C)) into a sum of products.

Comment: I usually use [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28not+A+and+D%29+and+%28not+D+or+%28B+and+C%29%29) for this sort of analysis.

Comment: this is off-topic in SO. try http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ there's a digital-logic tag

Comment: you can distribute AND with respect to OR, that will give you a sum of products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reviewed your equations and they are correct. On the other side, you can simplify your result as follows:

```
(~A & D) & (~D + (B & C)) = (~A & D & ~D) + (~A & D & B & C)
                          = ~A & B & C & D
```

Comment: Wow thanks for the help. Is there anyway that I can change X into a sum of products just as you did for Y, since I achieve a result of 0 and I'm unsure if it is possible to stray away from a numerical result in this situation?

Comment: Actually, wouldn't your result be a product of sums rather than a sum of products?

Comment: I'm also concerned with R5, can I just leave it as 1 or do I have to alter it some how to change it into a sum of products?

Comment: @MikeBlair my result is a product, not a sum of products because the result cannot be expressed as a sum. Regarding R5, you should leave it as 1 because it is 1 as your calculation shows.